# Is there a free API to get a geolocation for an Eircode?

Tags: geolocation

I'm currently creating a POC app, and for UK postcodes I'm using the excellent Postcodes.IO for geolocating UK postcodes, and I'd like to be able to do the same for Eircodes. The only solution I can find however is Google Maps, which, from my understanding, charges for even a small number of geolocation requests.

Is there any alternatives that are free, even if they are heavily rate limited?